# Does Hadoop copyFromLocal creates 2 copies? - 1 inside hdfs and other inside datanode?

Tags: hadoop

I have installed a pseudo distributed standalone hadoop version on Ubuntu present inside my vmware installed on my windows10.

I downloaded a file from internet and copied into ubuntu local directory /lab/data

I have created namenode and datanode folders(not hadoop folder) with name namenodep and datan1 in ubuntu. I have also created a folder inside hdfs as /input.

When I copied the file from ubuntu local to hdfs, why is that file is present in both the below directories?

```
$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /lab/data/Civil_List_2014.csv /input

$hadoop fs -ls /input/
input/Civil_List_2014.csv   ?????

$cd lab/hdfs/datan1/current
blk_3621390486220058643   ?????
blk_3621390486220058643_1121.meta
```

Basically I want to understand if it created 2 copies, 1 inside datan1 folder and the other inside hdfs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Only one copy is created.

When you create a file in HDFS, the contents of the file are stored on one of the disks of the Data Node. The disk location where the Data Node stores the data is determined by the configuration parameter: **dfs.datanode.data.dir** (present in hdfs-site.xml)

Check the description of this property:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///e:/hdpdatadn/dn</value>
    <description>Determines where on the local filesystem an DFS data node
    should store its blocks.  If this is a comma-delimited
    list of directories, then data will be stored in all named
    directories, typically on different devices.
    Directories that do not exist are ignored.
    </description>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
```

So above, the contents of your file HDFS file "/input/Civil_List_2014.csv", are stored in physical location: lab/hdfs/datan1/current/blk_3621390486220058643.

"blk_3621390486220058643_1121.meta" contains the check sum of the data stored in "blk_3621390486220058643".

This file may be small enough to be put in a single file. But, if a file is big (assuming > 256 MB and a Hadoop block size of 256 MB), then Hadoop splits the contents of the file into 'n' number of blocks and stores them on the disk. In that case, you will see 'n' number of "blk_*" files in the data node's data directory.

Also, since the replication factor is typically set to "3", 3 instances of the same block are created.

Comment: Thanks Manjunath for your reply, I have few clarifications__
1) If its a multi node cluster(say 3 datanode), then if the file was 1 TB, then where the .meta file and the actual file will be stored? Will it be divided among the 3 datanode.
2) and if the replication factor is 3, will the copy of .meta will be stored in other nodes or both the .meta and the actual file will be copied

I don't not have a hadoop cluster to setup this and test, hence posting these queries....Thanks

Comment: 1) Assuming a block size of 512MB, there could be a minimum of 2,048 blocks (For each 1 GB, there can be 2 blocks). The NameNode, will try to equally distribute the blocks among 3 data nodes. In each data node, the data is stored on the physical disk identified by the configuration parameter: dfs.datanode.data.dir. The corresponding ".meta" file is stored in the same folder.  2) If replication factor is 3, then 3 copies of each block is created and for each of the copies, corresponding ".meta" file is created. ".meta" contain checksum and is used for ensuring that the data is not corrupted.

Comment: So manjunath are you saying while making copies based on replication factor, each data node will have a copy of both the actual file as well as the   .meta file present?
Also is there a way to check the number of nodes connected to the cluster and their status?

Comment: Yes. Whichever node stores the data block, it will also store the corresponding .meta file. This is needed to ensure that there is no data corruption. The data nodes periodically check the data stored in each of the blocks and for that they need the .meta file which stores the file checksum. I am using Hadoop 2.7.1 (YARN). In the RM (Resource Manager) UI, you can see the number of active nodes. When you click on the "Nodes" link, it will give details about each of the nodes (Node state, Node address, Last Health Update etc.)

Comment: Thanks Manjunath, I think 2.7.1 Yarn is lot more advanced than its predecessor.

Answer (score 1):

The output from the `hadoop fs -ls /input/` command is actually showing you the metadata information and is not actually a physical file, its logical abstraction around the files which are hosted by datanode's. This metadata information is stored by NameNode.

The actual physical file's are split into blocks and are hosted by the datanode's in the path specified in the configuration in your case `lab/hdfs/datan1/current`.

Comment: Ashrith, thanks for your reply.<br/>
Can you please let me know when a file is split in a multinode cluster, will it place the different parts of one file(file size >1TB) in different nodes?

Comment: Yes. By default Hadoop splits the file into 128MB chunks and distributes them across the datanodes.